# datapoint can't be scraped with scrapy and python

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I want to scrape the title of an event.

For that I have written the following xpath commands, none of which worked:

```
response.xpath('//h1/@title').extract()

response.xpath('//id/class/h1/@title').extract()

response.xpath('//*[@class ="pd-lr-10 span9"]/h1/@title').extract()

response.xpath('//*[@class = "banner-container"]/h2').extract()

response.xpath('//*[@class = "overlay-h1"]/@title').extract()
```

All the commands above returned an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `xpath` to get the title:

```
response.xpath("//h1[@class='overlay-h1']/text()").extract_first()
```

Here is how you can give a go from any IDE:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class AlleventsTestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'titlegrabber'
    start_urls = ['https://allevents.in/kolkata/gourmet-cookies-workshop-on-21st-april/1649973561753390']

    def parse(self, response):
        title_one = response.xpath("//h1[@class='overlay-h1']/@title").extract_first()
        title_two = response.xpath("//h1[@class='overlay-h1']/text()").extract_first()

        yield {
                "TitleOne":title_one,
                "TitleTwo": title_two
            }

c = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',

})
c.crawl(AlleventsTestSpider)
c.start()
```

Comment: Not working. Even not getting empty list. No error also.

Comment: Okay I'm  gonna update my post with a working solution If you are familiar with [CrawlerProcess()](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html). Let me know. With [CrawlerProcess()](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html) you can run scrapy from any IDE as in, sublime, atom etc.

Comment: I donno but I wish to learn. Plz post your solution. I'll give my best to understand that. By the way, after changing my Internet network and ID also, I can't see the output.

Comment: I've added the script which should give you the same title twice.

Answer (score 0):

These ones work. It might be due to 503 error. In scrapy shell, use `view(response)` to check whether you get the page or not. After that, you can go with one of these selectors.

```
response.xpath('//*[@class ="pd-lr-10 span9"]/h1/@title').extract()

response.xpath('//*[@class = "overlay-h1"]/@title').extract()

response.xpath('//h1/@title').extract()
```

Note: If you did not enable USER AGENT in your setting file, that might help you. Or you can change your IP address.

Comment: I checked with other sites by writing xpath commands specifically for those sites. They worked. Only for this site, whatever I am writing, am getting an empty list. :(

Comment: please read the note that I added later. Add USER AGENT or reset your IP address if you can. Because nothing is wrong with the xpath that I showed

Comment: Hey I wrote this command on scrapy shell and it worked: scrapy shell "https://allevents.in/kolkata/gourmet-cookies-workshop-on-21st-april/1649973561753390" -s USER_AGENT="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"

But how should I write the scrapy crawl command?

Comment: in settings.py file, you can find the USER AGENT row, add it to there.